# Emacs, Windows, Tramp, Plink still doesn't work

Tags: emacs, ssh, emacs24, tramp, plink

When I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> `/ssh:<hostname>/<filename>`, I get the following error message:

```
plink -l <mydefaultusername> -ssh ssh && exit || exit
Unable to open connection:
Host does not exist
```

It seems like the hostname is lost and it tries to connect to a host named `ssh`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file name lacks a `:`.  It should be `/ssh:<hostname>:<filename>`.